# saving JSON response as an object rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json, model

I am looking to clarify my understanding here or actually understand... I have a a JSON response like so

```
  {
 "resultCount":1,
  "results": [
 {"kind":"ebook", "artistId":545975179, "artistName":"Gareth Halfacree", "price":9.99, 
 "description":"<p><b>Make the most out of the world&rsquo;s first truly compact  computer<\/b><\/p><p>It's the size of a credit card, it can be charged like a smartphone,  it runs on open-source Linux, and it holds the promise of bringing programming and playing  to millions at low cost. And now you can learn how to use this amazing computer from its co-creator, Eben Upton, in <i>Raspberry Pi User Guide<\/i>. Cowritten with Gareth Halfacree, this guide gets you up and running on Raspberry Pi, whether you're an educator, hacker, hobbyist, or kid. Learn how to connect your Pi to other hardware, install software, write basic programs, and set it up to run robots, multimedia centers, and more.<\/p><ul><li>Gets you up and running on Raspberry Pi, a high-tech computer the size of a credit card <\/li><li>Helps educators teach students how to program <\/li><li>Covers connecting Raspberry Pi to other hardware, such as monitors and keyboards, how to install software, and how to configure Raspberry Pi <\/li><li>Shows you how to set up Raspberry Pi as a simple productivity computer, write basic programs in Python, connect to servos and sensors, and drive a robot or multimedia center <\/li><\/ul><p>Adults, kids, and devoted hardware hackers, now that you've got a Raspberry Pi, get the very most out of it with <i>Raspberry Pi User Guide<\/i>.<\/p>", "genreIds":["10017", "38", "9027"], "releaseDate":"2012-08-30T07:00:00Z", "currency":"USD", "genres":["Computers", "Books", "Computers & Internet"], "trackId":559783692, "trackName":"Raspberry Pi User Guide",  "artistIds":[545975179],  "artworkUrl60":"http://a2.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Publication/v4/ba/a8/2c/baa82ce0-2ac7-7026-04da-6f74bc97b403/9781118464496.60x60-50.jpg", "artistViewUrl":"https://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/gareth-halfacree/id545975179?mt=11&uo=4", "trackCensoredName":"Raspberry Pi User Guide", "formattedPrice":"$9.99", "artworkUrl100":"http://a4.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Publication/v4/ba/a8/2c/baa82ce0-2ac7-7026-04da-6f74bc97b403/9781118464496.100x100-75.jpg", "trackViewUrl":"https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/raspberry-pi-user-guide/id559783692?mt=11&uo=4", "averageUserRating":2.5, "userRatingCount":5}]
```

}

and i would like to save it certain values to my book model after clicking a link_to ( i have read that link_to is more secure than say button_to)

So i have a module that handles the parsing which is included in my controller

```
    module Book::BookFinder

BOOK_URL = 'https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?isbn='

def book_search(search)
    response = HTTParty.get(BOOK_URL + "#{search}", :headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => 'application/json' })
results = JSON.parse(response.body)["results"]
end
    end
```

Within my books controller

```
class BookController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authenticate_admin_user!
include Book::BookFinder

def searchbook

end

def results
 results = book_search(params[:search])
 @results = results

end

def savebook

Book.create(:author => response["results"]["artistName"])

end
end
```

(Firstly i look at this and think that using rails restful practices would be better, so using the new and create methods?)

I have a link_to setup to post the data to my model

```
<%= link_to 'Save Book', savebook_path,  :method => :post %>
```

and my routes

```
scope :controller  => :book do
get 'searchbook'
get 'results'
post 'savebook'

end
```

So at present i get a error message when clicking the link_to, it says wrong number of arguments (0 for 1).

because I am getting the data externally it has thrown me a little, when dealing with posting data from a form using new, create, edit etc it makes sense, but here i am a little lost

Could anyone offer some advice/solutions to help me understand what needs to happen

Thanks

Comment: What does this line do? `json_response = JSON.parse["results"]` ? Where is the json response that should be parsed and stored?

Comment: I was under the impression that this line parses the returned JSON object?

Comment: Not at all. `json_response = JSON.parse["results"]` is something like `res = JSON.parse` `json_response = res['results']`.

Comment: im confused, this is all very new so forgive me for mistakes like this. When i am getting the data from the api i use results = JSON.parse(response.body)["results"] which works fine.  do i need to do the same again when saving the data? little lost here

Comment: Guess you get data from api in another action, not in the `savebook`? If so, you don't have access to the response and parsed JSON any longer. You need to pass to the savebook action either original search term, ask and parse the api again; or pass the returning JSON as string, or build Book object in previous action and submit it to books controller. Do you have one (books controller with `create` action)?

Comment: yes data is collected in a module in a method (which is then included in my book controller) I have a books controller but no create action in it yet, i was using the savebook action to handle the creation? think i may need to start again here wont I.

Comment: I have updated my question based on your previous comment, though i just noticed that you have posted an answer, would that still be relevant based on updated info in question? I understand that as i have called the api once in my module I dont have to call it again when trying to save as i already have the info?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll suggest you change the architecture a bit. Assume you receive the api response in results action:

```
def results
  ...
  @results = book_search(params[:search])
  @book = Book.new
  @book.author = results[0]["artistName"]
  ...
end

def create
  @book = Book.new(params[:book])
  if @book.save
    redirect_to @book, notice: 'Book was successfully saved'
  else
    render action:new
  end
end
```

results view, instead of

```
<%= link_to 'Save Book', savebook_path,  :method => :post %>
```

use

```
...
<%= form_for @book do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :author %>
  ...
  <%= f.submit 'Save book' %>
<% end %>
```

And absolutely standard Books controller with create action

Comment: thank you for updating, any reason why i now get undefined method `new' for Book:Module when submitting a search

Comment: would it be a naming conflict as my module is  Book::BookFinder and I am creating an object called Book?

Comment: ok so it seems as if a module cannot be instanced and a class would need to be used..Unsure where to go from here